# How to deal with updates which are too fast for UI?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am updating my UILabel like this in a loop:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.runningLabelView.text = text
}
```

`text` is being updated in a loop 60 times a second for a total of 1 second.

This seems to be too fast for the UI as the text keeps updating several seconds after the first 1 second.

Can I skip any pending text updates during this loop, so text updates complete with the completion of the loop?

Comment: You need to show more code. There's no context here.

Comment: Consider syncing your text updates with the screen refresh. Have a look at CADisplayLink. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that the value of `text` is captured when the closure is added to the dispatch queue, not when the closure executes.  Which means that each individual text assignment will occur in sequence.

One solution would be to use a property rather than a captured local variable.  That way the label will be set to the current property value rather than an out of date captured value:

```
self.messageText = someNewValue
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.runningLabelView.text = self.messageText
}
```

Another, probably better, approach would be to dispatch fewer updates, but you would need to provide more information.